# Thunderbolt options for ASUS Z10PE-16/4L

Tags: motherboard, desktop, pcie, thunderbolt

I'd like to add Thunderbolt I/O to an ASUS Z10PE-D16/4L motherboard. Hopefully through a PCIe card. It seems [ASUS ThunderboltEX II](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboard-Accessories/ThunderboltEX_II/) isn't compatible, and [HP Thunderbolt-2 PCIe 1-Port I/O Card F3F43AT](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1039491-REG/hp_f3f43at_hp_thunderbolt_2_pcie_1_port_i_o.html) isn't compatible with anything past HP's products. Are there any other PCIe cards that could or are known to work? It doesn't have to be TB 2 or 3.